# Mysql single query join 3 table and get all the results

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i want to list all the song for the album and i want to list all the artist for individual song see below for example.

```
1. Song Title 1
   - Artist 1, Artist 2, Artist 3    note:(all this individual artist have link to there artist page)
2. Song Title 2
   - Artist 1, Artist 2
3. Song Title 3
   - Artist 1, Artist 2, Artist 3
```

My tables are **song, album, artist, song_artist**

song table

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | song_name | album_id |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 1  | Title 1   | 2        |
| 2  | Title 2   | 2        |
| 3  | Title 3   | 2        |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

album table

```
+----+------------+
| id | album_name |
+----+------------+
| 1  | Album 1    |
| 2  | Album 2    |
| 3  | Album 3    |
+----+------------+
```

artist table

```
+----+-------------+
| id | artist_name |
+----+-------------+
| 1  | Artist 1    |
| 2  | Artist 2    |
| 3  | Artist 3    |
+----+-------------+
```

song_artist table

```
+--------+--------------+---------+
| id     | song_id      |artist_id|
+--------+--------------+---------+
| 1      | 1            | 1       |
| 2      | 1            | 5       |
| 3      | 1            | 3       |
| 4      | 2            | 3       |
| 5      | 2            | 1       |
| 6      | 3            | 2       |
| 7      | 3            | 1       |
+--------+--------------+---------+
```

This is my current code.

```
$id =$_GET['id']; *// Get album id from url*
$query = "SELECT id, song_name, FROM song WHERE album_id = '".$id."'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("h".mysql_error());
while( $song = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo $song['song_name'];
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT artist.artist_name as artist_name, artist.id as aid
FROM artist
INNER JOIN song_artist
ON artist.id = song_artist.artist_id
WHERE song_artist.song_id = '".$song['id']."' ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
echo "<a href='".$row['sid']."'>".$row['artist_name']."</a>, ";
}
}
```

how do i write mysql single query to get all results in php?

Thank you for your help in advance.

James.

**Ok Now i got the result what i want, thank for every one.**

```
$query = "select s.id song_id, s.song_name, group_concat(art.artist_name) artname, a.id
        from song s 
        left outer join album a on a.id = s.album_id
        left outer join song_artist sa on sa.song_id = s.id
        left outer join artist art on art.id = sa.artist_id
        WHERE a.id= '".$id."'
        GROUP BY song_id";
```

Comment: Is this homework? If so, have a look at [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)). If not, have a look anyway! ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.song_name, a.artist_name, al.album_name
FROM artist a
LEFT JOIN song_artist sa ON sa.artist_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN song s ON s.id = sa.song_id
LEFT JOIN album al ON al.id = s.album_id
```

More info on [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

Comment: this code show only one artist for the song but the song have 3 artist

Comment: Yes, because only 1 artist in "song_artist" is in the table "artist" (there are no artist with id=5 given in your data). If you want to get _all_ the artists whether they have songs or not, take a look at LEFT JOIN (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

Comment: in that image i didn't put all record that image i created because i want to show how my tables are designed but in the real song_artist table have artist_id 3,5,6 for song_id 5

Comment: Try with the edited answer using LEFT JOIN, should get what you want.

Comment: thanks for your time to help me out but it's not giving me what i want.

Comment: You need to use the `GROUP_CONCAT` function to get the results that he wants. (All artists in the same row).

Answer (score 1):

This gets you the songs + artists for album 1.

```
SELECT song_name, group_concat(artist_name) 
FROM song 
LEFT JOIN song_artist ON song.id=song_artist.song_id 
LEFT JOIN artist ON song_artist.artist_id=artist.id 
WHERE song.album_id=1
```

Note that you did answer this question in another spot as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select s.song_name ,art.artist_name,a.album_name from Song
join song_artist sa on sa.Song_id = s.Song_id
join Album a on a.album_id = s.Album_id
join Artist art on art.id = sa.artist_id
```

Comment: you have error in this code you didn't include the artist table anywhere then how can you get the artist name from the artist table. this code not working.